# Escaping Closure captures non-escaping parameter dispatch

Tags: swift

I am getting the error: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter dispatch. This error is coming on MovieService().getMovies line.

```
typealias ActionCreator = (_ dispatch: (Action) -> (), _ getState: () -> AppState) -> ()

func fetchMovies() -> ActionCreator   {
    
    return { dispatch, getState in
        
        MovieService.getMovies(url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2&apikey=YOURKEY") { result in
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let movies):
                if let movies = movies {
                    dispatch(.populateMovies(movies))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) documentation states:

> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as
> an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.
> When you declare a function that takes a closure as one of its
> parameters, you can write @escaping before the parameter’s type to
> indicate that the closure is allowed to escape.

By default a closure is `nonescaping` like your `dispatch` parameter, but you are calling it inside an `escaping` closure which probably is the closure that you pass as a parameter in `getMovies` function.

The solution is simple, just add `@escaping` before the `dispatch` parameter type:

```
typealias ActionCreator = (_ dispatch: @escaping (Action) -> (), _ getState: () -> AppState) -> ()
```